# Entity Framework - LazyLoad com propriedade que permite null

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

O que acontece com uma busca que utiliza o `include` do `Entity Framework` em uma propriedade que pode ser nula.

```
var ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencia
            .Include("Pessoa")
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == 3);
```

Esse objeto `ocorrencia` pode ter a propriedade `Pessoa` como `null`.

A `model`:

```
public partial class Ocorrencia
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
}

public class Pessoa
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
    }
```

O objeto Ocorrência será retornado com o objeto Pessoa nulo, ou nada será retornado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O objeto Ocorrência será retornado com o objeto Pessoa nulo, ou nada será retornado?

Pelo seu mapeamento, nada será retornado, pois a resolução de carga antecipada será pelo `INNER JOIN` por causa disso:

```
public int PessoaId { get; set; }
```

Para resolver como `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, teria que ser:

```
public int? PessoaId { get; set; }
```